# Centering images inside Bootstrap gridsystem

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to center my images inside the Bootstrap grid like this - https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJiiS.jpg; the image should be centered in the blue box (both on desktop and mobile).

here's my html:

```
  <div class="row">        
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
     <div class="image img-responsive">         
       <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive " src="http://i.imgur.com/GFZbJZr.jpg" border="0"></a>            
     </div>
    </div>      
   </div> 

   <div class="row">        
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
     <div class="image img-responsive">         
       <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive " src="http://i.imgur.com/pJF2nvM.jpg" border="0"></a>            
     </div>
    </div>      
   </div> 

   <div class="row">        
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
     <div class="image img-responsive">         
       <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive " src="http://i.imgur.com/JYYrpgD.jpg" border="0"></a>            
     </div>
    </div>      
   </div>
```

Comment: Skelly's answer is correct. Add class "center-block" to the image

Comment: Cab's comment is correct, follow Skelly's instructions.

Comment: haha, thanks. I have it working, but I have one more issue, check my comment on Skelly's solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use the Bootstrap 3 `center-block` class in your images...

### Demo: http://bootply.com/104077

I also simplfied your markup to remove unnecessary nesting..

```
<div class="row">        
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

       <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://i.imgur.com/GFZbJZr.jpg" border="0"></a>            

   </div> 
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

       <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://i.imgur.com/pJF2nvM.jpg" border="0"></a>            

   </div> 
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

       <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://i.imgur.com/JYYrpgD.jpg" border="0"></a>            

   </div>       
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I also have a hover effect which has color overlay and a description in it, and I need to center that as well, how would I go about at centering that? http://bootply.com/104081

Answer (score 1):

should be just a matter of css

```
.image a {
display: block;
}
.image a img {
margin 0 auto;
display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
img {
margin:0 auto;
width:50%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick ;)

```
.image.img-responsive {
    text-align: center; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add in your css:

```
div.image {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: It is recommended to provide an example working properly. For example in http://jsfiddle.net/